# How can I return an object using reduce()?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Write a function called `getSongCountByArtist` which takes in an array of songs and returns an object. The keys in the object should be artist names, and the values should be the number of songs by that artist in the original array.

My code Solution:

```js
function getSongCountByArtist(arr){
      return arr.reduce(function(acc,val){
                    let artistSong = val.name;
                    let songNo = artistSong.length;

                    return acc[val.artist] + songNo;

              }, {})
}

getSongCountByArtist(songs); //NaN
```

My data source https://github.com/PJMantoss/iterators2/blob/master/data.js

problem explanation: The function is supposed to return an object with artist names as keys and number of songs by the artist as values. But On running `getSongCountByArtist`(songs) it returns **NaN**. How can I refactor my code to work? Thank you

Comment: Change `return acc[val.artist] + songNo;` to `acc[val.artist] = songNo; return acc;`. However, doing ` let songNo = artistSong.length;` is probably wrong as well. It seems to count the number of characters on the artist's name. But without knowing the structure of the input data there isn't much we can do to help fix that.

Comment: Hi Felix! The input data is an array of song objects. You can view it here https://github.com/PJMantoss/iterators2/blob/master/data.js  But I've refactored the code and it now works. Please see my answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it. I refactored the code and it now returns the correct data. See it below

```
function getSongCountByArtist(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (acc, val) {
      if (acc[val.artist] === undefined) acc[val.artist] = 0;
      acc[val.artist]++;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  } 
//test
getSongCountByArtist(songs);
```

Thank you